# Optimize formatting from aggregated return from Sequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a query from sequel that is returning something like this:

```
posts = [
  <Post: @attributes={ id: 1, title: 'Foo', text: 'Bar', user_id: 21, user: <User: @attributes={ id: 21, name: 'John'}>}>, 
  <Post: @attributes={ id: 2, title: 'Bar', text: 'Foo', user_id: 21, user: <User: @attributes={ id: 21, name: 'John'}>}>, 
  <Post: @attributes={ id: 3, title: 'FooBar', text: 'FooBar', user_id: 19, user: <User: @attributes={ id: 19, name: 'Jane'}>}>
]
```

An array of `Post` and `User` objects.

I want to return it like this to the user:

```
json = {
  posts:[
    { id: 1, title: 'Foo', text: 'Bar', user_id: 21 }, 
    { id: 2, title: 'Bar', text: 'Foo', user_id: 21 },
    { id: 3, title: 'FooBar', text: 'FooBar', user_id: 19 }
  ],
  users: [
    { id: 21, name: 'John'},
    { id: 19, name: 'Jane'}
  ]
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to extract this Hash from the original array?
This is the code I'm using for it right now:

```
def prepare_json(array)
  posts = []
  users = Hash[]
  array.each do |item|
    posts.push(item.post)

    # user id is unique so I use it to avoid duplication on
    # the users array 
    users[item.user.id.to_sym] = item.user
  end
  { posts: posts, users: users.values }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
users = posts.map{|h| h.delete(:user)}.uniq
json = {posts: posts, users: users}
```

Result:

```
{
  :posts=>[{:id=>1, :title=>"Foo", :text=>"Bar", :user_id=>21}, {:id=>2, :title=>"Bar", :text=>"Foo", :user_id=>21}, {:id=>3, :title=>"FooBar", :text=>"FooBar", :user_id=>19}],
  :users=>[{:id=>21, :name=>"John"}, {:id=>19, :name=>"Jane"}]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer that the array returned by Sequel is not composed by hashes, but by Post and User objects. Your answer still works in this case if you use `uniq(&:id)`.
I also need to remove the user from inside the `Post` object before returning it